# How to query below scenario using aggregate query in mongodb preferably without unwinding

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

How to query below scenario using aggregate query in mongodb

Lets say docs look like

```
{
_id:"1",
subjId:"abc",
Grades:[{
   rank:1,
   GradeId:234,
   processedDate: 2020-10-12,
   completedDate: 2020-12-15
   },{
   rank:2,
   GradeId:234,
   processedDate: 2020-12-15,
   },{
   rank:3,
   GradeId:234,
   processedDate: 2020-12-14,
   }
]
}

{
_id:2,
subjId:"xyz",
Grades:[{
   rank:1,
   GradeId:234,
   processedDate: 2020-10-12,
   completedDate: 2020-12-15
   },{
   rank:2,
   GradeId:234,
   processedDate: 2020-12-14,
   },{
   rank:3,
   GradeId:234,
   processedDate: 2020-12-15,
   }
]
}
```

criteria to search
1)grade id will be provided as input
2)completed date should be null
3) min (rank)
4)max (processed Date)

when gradeid is provided as 234 it should return only subid abc because rank2 object satisfies above conditions where completed date is null, 2 is minimum rank and 2020-12-15 is max processeddate but where as for subid xyz doc min rank and max processedDates are from differentObject.

Comment: Grades is an array and you have multi match for grade id. Unwind is the correct option. I am not quite sure about MR.

Comment: What is your expected result as per your documents, full record or sub object of Grades array?

Comment: full record @turivishal

Answer (score 0):

- `$match` you conditions
- `$unwind` deconstruct `Grades` array
- `$sort` by `rank` in ascending order and `processedDate` in descending order
- `$group` by `_id` and re-construct `Grades` array
- `$limit` get first document

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      Grades: {
        $elemMatch: {
          GradeId: 234,
          completedDate: { $exists: false }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { $unwind: "$Grades" },
  {
    $sort: {
      "Grades.rank": 1,
      "Grades.processedDate": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      subjId: { $first: "$subjId" },
      Grades: { $push: "$Grades" }
    }
  },
  { $limit: 1 }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DEZbSz2ryb3)